# CSS Menu Not Clickable Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular JS and bootstrap.

The problem is my menu can't be clicked on Chrome as if theres something over it?

My sites here http://www.jamballa.com/platform/app/#/blogs I really don't know much about CSS so I think it's a problem there.

Any advice would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Which element in particular cant you click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your .view-animate-container is over your menu. To put the menu higher than the .view-animate-container simple add a z-index to your .sidey container like this:

```
.sidey{z-index:10;}
```